# how can I not select last element of styled component

Tags: css, styled-components

this is my code structure

```
const StyledArticle = styled.article``;

const StyledDiv = styled.div``; 

 <StyledArticle>
   <StyledDiv>1</StyledDiv>
   <StyledDiv>2</StyledDiv>  
   <StyledDiv>3</StyledDiv> 
   <StyledDiv>4</StyledDiv>  
 </StyledArticle>
```

how can I add css StyledDiv 1,2,3 except 4th StyledDiv.

**without add any css statement in StyledArticle**

no js, jquery using only css.

Comment: Do you want to apply CSS to StyledDiv 1, 2, 3 or do you want to programmatically obtain StyledDiv 1,2,3.

Comment: I want apply CSS to StyledDiv 1,2,3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a combination of `:not()` and `:last-of-type` pseudo selectors:

```css
StyledDiv:not(:last-of-type) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<StyledArticle>
  <StyledDiv>1</StyledDiv>
  <StyledDiv>2</StyledDiv>
  <StyledDiv>3</StyledDiv>
  <StyledDiv>4</StyledDiv>
</StyledArticle>
```

A styled component:

```
const StyledDiv = styled.div`
    &:not(:last-of-type) {
      color: red;
    }
`;
```

Comment: like  ```const StyledDiv = styled.div`
   &:not(:last-of-type) {
`  
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the CSS :not(:last-child) selector. It does exactly what it means. It selects elements that are not the last child of the parent.

```
<style> 
StyledArticle StyledDiv:not(:last-child) {
  background: red;
}
</style>
```